# Closures and access to parent variables no longer on the execution stack

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

New to closures and the inner workings of JS. I have a somewhat stable grasp of execution contexts and the associated objects within it. And while I know how to identify a closure and what it may yield, I don't quite see where the parent variables reside, once the parent function is popped from the stack.

I'd assume they become properties of the closure's variable object? But you know where that leads.

Comment: do you have  sample code what you are referring to ?

Comment: This was already posted (also well-written): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures

Answer (score 0):

> I don't quite see where the parent variables reside

They reside in scope. How that is expressed in the computer's memory is an implementation detail of the specific JavaScript runtime (which is probably written in C or C++).